# 1 day VaR vs 10 day VaR

Tags: volatility, value-at-risk

Even while using historical simulation VaR, 1 day VaR is converted into 10 day VaR by multiplying 1 day VaR by Sqrt(10) for regulatory reporting purposes.

What are the underlying assumptions for doing this and how can those assumptions be tested statistically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What are the underlying assumptions for doing this

**Assumption:** Historical returns are lognormally distributed with no autocorrelation.

> can those assumptions be tested statistically

**Testing:** $\sqrt{xy}  =  \sqrt{x} \sqrt{y}$

Substitute time $t$ and variance $\sigma^2$ for $x$ and $y$ respectively

$\sqrt{t\sigma^2} = \sqrt{t} \sqrt{\sigma^2} = \sigma\sqrt{t}$

**Some links for you to check out if you would like to investigate further:**

https://eprints.lse.ac.uk/24827/1/dp439.pdf

[Square root of time](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7495/square-root-of-time)

https://www.investopedia.com/articles/04/101304.asp

Answer (score 3):

Practically, I can tell you the sqare root assumption doesn't actually hold in practice--vol is not actually homoskedastic as a result of underlying returns not being iid (the scale tends to fall just short of the square of 12 in equities as a result of heterskedasticity).

A quick google turned up [this](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/papers/paper18/dsi.pdf), which seems to walk through precisely what you're asking about.  Would probably be as good as any place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Do we actually need lognormal returns as amdopt states? As long as returns are i.i.d., we have $\textrm{E}(r_tr_{t+1})=0$ and as a result $\textrm{Variance}(\sum_1^{10}r_t)=10\textrm{Variance}(r_t)$, so the VaR which is the threshold for a left tail weight of (say) $\alpha$ is scaled by $\sqrt{10}$.

Answer (score -3):

one-day VaR cannot be converted into ten-day VaR, as Z ~ N(r, sigma) should provide a different distribution over one-day, limited time horizon.